# What is the best way to refactor a condition with multiple || and &&

Tags: oop, refactoring, logical-operators

What is the best way to refactor this code?

```
boolean result =
                (!method1(response) && method2(response)) ||
                (method1(response) && !method3(response)) ||
                (method1(response) && method3(response) && !method4(response) && !method5(response)) ||
                (method1(response) && method3(response) && !method4(response) && method5(response) && method6(response));
```

`method1() ... method6()` are just helper methods that are parsing different parts of the response object and returning a `boolean`.
`boolean result` is not the only field being built using logical operators between `method1() ... method6()`

Comment: Based on the question title, my first response was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form so the question is likely to be closed as highly opinion based